# What is the modern LDS view towards multiple Heavenly Mothers/wives of members of the Godhead?

Tags: lds

[The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavenly_Mother_(Mormonism)) on 'Heavenly Mother' notes that:

> Brigham Young taught that God the Father was polygamous, although teachings on Heavenly Mothers were never as popular and disappeared from official rhetoric after the end of LDS polygamy in 1904 (although existing polygynous marriages lasted into the 1950s). Top leaders used the examples of the polygamy of God the Father in defense of the practice and this teaching was widely accepted by the late-1850s. Apostle Orson Pratt taught in an official church periodical that "We have now clearly shown that God the Father had a plurality of wives," and that after her death, Mary (the mother of Jesus) may have become another eternal polygamous wife of God. One scholar interpreted a 1976 LDS manual as alluding to this teaching. Author Carol Lynn Pearson stated that a seminary teacher from her youth fervently taught that there were multiple Heavenly Mothers.

My understanding is that the modern Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day saints unambiguously bans plural marriage in this lifetime, but allows one person to be sealed to multiple people in the celestial realm (eg, a widower who remarries after his wife's death and has two wives in heaven).  Given this, what is the modern teaching of the Church with regards to the idea that members of the Godhead have multiple wives? More specifically, if this teaching has not been repudiated, are *all* the wives collectively 'Heavenly Mothers', or is *one particular* wife have a special position as **the** Heavenly Mother?

(I apologize for using the now disapproved abbreviation 'LDS' in the title—unfortunately, the full name of the Church wouldn't fit well into a short title)

Answer (score 5):

There is very little in regards to the doctrine of Heavenly Mother and not much has changed in recent years. Most references to Heavenly Mother are singular (not plural), and there is no expounded doctrine within the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints in regards to Heavenly Mother.

> The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints teaches that all human beings, male and female, are beloved spirit children of heavenly parents, a Heavenly Father and a Heavenly Mother. ... Prophets have taught that our heavenly parents work together for the salvation of the human family. ... As with many other truths of the gospel, **our present knowledge about a Mother in Heaven is limited.**<sup>1</sup>

<sub>1 [Mother in Heaven](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics-essays/mother-in-heaven?lang=eng)</sub>